# Singleton class method in static library in iOS

Tags: ios, static, singleton

I have a static library which contains a Singleton Class Method, I call it in an `(IBAction)` function, the first time I call it  is ok, but the second crashed, and no error information,
the singleton class method as follows:

```
   +(myClass *)sharedClient{
    static myClass *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[[myClass alloc] init] autorelease];

    });

    return _sharedClient;
    }
```

and I call it as follows:

```
   -(IBAction) action

    {
        [myClass sharedClient] action];
    }
```

Comment: `no error information` - Are you sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending autorelease to the new object inside the shared accessor. The next time the autorelease pool pops, the shared object will get released and then destroyed. Simply remove the autorelease, and the crash should fix itself.

Comment: it really works, but i don't use ARC, when should i release it?

Comment: As its a (non-strict) singleton accessor ... you don't release it. This is why to be extremely careful in using the singleton pattern - if the shared object turns out to be using too much memory, you may need to rethink your application's design to use a less strict approach. Its fine if you don't run into that problem, however.